# How to solve a Mercurial case-folding collision with branches involved?

Tags: merge, mercurial, case-sensitive

Today I went to merge a branch back into an old branch and got told that I couldn't update to the original branch due to a case-folding collision.

My repo looks a bit like this:

- default branch, revision 1: add most files.
- default branch, revision 2: adds files `xyz` and `XYZ`. Presumably was done on Linux machine. This was back in 2008.
- default branch revisions 3-35: various other changes, no problems
- revision 36: new feature branch added
- feature branch, revision 71: notice on Windows that Sourcetree is reporting that `xyz` is deleted, so I commit that, which becomes...
- feature branch, revision 72: this is the change that explicitly removes BOTH `xyz` and `XYZ`

At this point, I wanted to merge the feature branch back into the default, but it will not let me update back to version 71, or any other version except revision 1 when `xyz` was not in the repo at all. Obviously every changeset from 2 through to 71 is 'polluted' with these 2 files that I could only ever check out as 1 on my Windows and Mac machines.

The usual suggested solution - https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions - does not work: it says *"hg status should show the troublesome file in state 'R' and all other files in state '!'"*, but when I follow the steps, it actually shows all other files in state 'M', which is obviously not what I want and implies some data loss would occur if I proceeded.

Additionally, I would suspect I can never perform the desired merge on Windows or MacOS, because I need revision 35 to be in a usable state before I can pull anything into it.

Is there anything I can do here to fix it? All my files are safe, and I am also willing to lose all data and revisions in the `xyz` files to get this repo working again, but I would really prefer not to lose the repo and the changelog entirely.

Comment: You can always do that merge in a VM with an OS which supports case differentiation in filesnames

Comment: I ended up having to do basically this, except on a remote server as I have no VM capability handy.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a proper fix for this, so I had to borrow a Linux box to get a case-sensitive filesystem. Then the fix was:

1. Copy the entire repository to a Linux machine with Mercurial installed.
2. Revert/update to the latest revision on the default branch that had the 2 files with clashing names in the working copy, and `hg rename` them to names that didn't clash. Reapply any other changes since then.
3. Update to the revision on the other branch, do the same thing.
4. Perform the merge as normal.
5. Copy the repo and working directory back to Windows.
6. Remove/rename/modify the 2 renamed files so that only 1 remains, with whatever name is desired.

Steps 4 and 5 could probably have been done in either order.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the OP, the primary resource for guidance on managing case conflicts of the type described is https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions

The directions given there are perhaps not as clear as they could be, so here is an annotated transcript based on one of the procedures given there.

We start with a repository named "repo", which has two files: `a.txt` and `A.txt`.  On a remote machine:

```
REMOTE_MACHINE $ hg files
A.txt
a.txt
```

Now let's assume that `repo` has somehow been cloned onto the local machine (the computer on which the case-folding problem occurs).  This might have been done using a command such as:

```
$ hg clone --noupdate "ssh://REMOTE/DIRECTORY/repo" # illustrative
```

If you don't want to alter `repo` on the local machine, then you could (for example) clone it, as by:

```
$ hg clone --noupdate repo xrepo  # illustrative and optional
```

Now cd into the directory of the repository to be modified, e.g.

```
$ cd repo   # or perhaps: cd xrepo
```

You might want to verify the integrity of the repository:

```
$ hg verify
```

Next come the two lines of black magic:

```
$ hg debugsetparents tip 
$ hg debugrebuildstate
```

At this point, Mercurial will think you have the `tip` checked out, 
and that all the files are missing (status '!').  In our case:

```
$ hg st -dram
! A.txt
! a.txt
```

Now we will run some ordinary hg commands to address the case-folding problem.  Let's begin by extracting the files of interest manually:

```
$ hg cat a.txt > lc.a.txt
$ hg cat A.txt > uc.A.txt
```

Now remove the two problematic files from the repo:

```
$ hg -v remove --after a.txt A.txt
removing A.txt
removing a.txt
```

(The `--after` option above in effect instructs Mercurial to handle the fact that the files being removed (from the repository) are not on disk.)

Now we're back to normal.  We might want to check in our renamed files:

```
$ hg -v add lc.a.txt uc.A.txt
adding lc.a.txt
adding uc.A.txt

$ hg st -dram
A lc.a.txt
A uc.A.txt
R A.txt
R a.txt

$ hg commit --message "renamed a.txt to lc.a.txt and A.txt to uc.A.txt"
$ hg files
lc.a.txt
uc.A.txt

$ cat lc.a.txt
lowercase a
$ cat uc.A.txt
uppercase A
$

# Verify that the original files are still there:
$ hg files --rev 0
A.txt
a.txt
```

At this point, to checkout all the other files, you could run: hg revert --all

Comment: I did mention this exact URL in the question, and stated that it did not work for me.

Comment: I've included an actual transcript.  Hopefully it will be more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't look significantly different from the instructions I followed, which caused a lot of files to be modified. Perhaps the fact that the edit needs to be done many revisions in the past is being missed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in a while, but I've used the **convert extension** in the past to clean up case folding on Windows.

Note: I'm making the assumption that this is an essentially *private repository* to which you have exclusive access. If that is the case then this approach would work. (Even if that is not the case, this would still work technically but you'd have to publish it to other people as a new repo since the conversion described below would generate all new changeset IDs.)

You can do this using the convert extension to Mercurial, and the `filemap` option.

> Convert can ... rename files during conversion, when you
>   supply it a mapping via the --filemap option.
>
> The filemap is a file that specifies which files are to be included,
>   renamed, or omitted.
>
> Each line can contain one of the following directives:
>   ...
>
> ```
> rename from/file to/file
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The rename directive renames a file or directory. To rename from a
>   subdirectory into the root of the repository, use . as the path to
>   rename to.

The command line to do this would be something like:

`hg convert` `--filehmap filemap.txt` `path\to\source\repo` `path\to\converted\repo`

Where `filemap.txt` has to include something like:

`rename path\to\XYZ path\to\xyz_which_was_uppercase`

The conversion process should rename ALL "instances" of XYZ on all branches, so the fact that branches are involved I think becomes irrelevant.

[Documentation.](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap)